# MobileFirst platform 6.3 returning incorrect Arabic text

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have development version of Mobile First Platform 6.3 on my machine and a production version (also 6.3) hosted on a server, the local version is returning the Arabic text correctly while the server is returning corrupted Arabic. The requests happen as follows:

My machine > Local mfp server > backend
My machine > remote mfp server > backend

I'm using the same machine to send the same request which goes to the same back-end and gets processed by the same exact adapter, the only difference is the mfp the request goes through.

I did notice the following though, the backend returns the Arabic text as Octal digits (\XXX\XXX\XXX), but in some other services from the same backend the Arabic text is returned as UTF-8 in \uXXXX format, in such cases the Arabic displays correctly.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the fix for this issue is now available on IBM Fix Central - download the latest 6.3 iFix.

I believe this is related to: APAR IBM PI39922 UNICODE PARAMETERS ARE ENCODED INCORRECTLY UPON BEING PASSED TO A MOBILEFIRST ADAPTER.

This APAR fix is not available for MobileFirst Platform 6.3.

To receive the fix you will need to open a PMR (support ticket). 
There is no known local workaround for this issue.

Comment: If I open support ticket they'll send me a patch for the MFP?

Comment: You'll receive an iFix, yes.